# Expressing odd numbers as a prime minus $a^2+a$

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers

I am looking for results about expressing odd numbers in the form

$$p-a^2-a,$$

where $p$ is a prime and $a$ is a positive integer.

Assuming [Bunyakovsky conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bunyakovsky_conjecture) this is easy as $x^2+ x+c$ are always irreducible when $c$ is odd, but I am hoping there is a result on this.

Comment: Besides $x^2+ x+c$ being irreducible, it needs to not be always divisible by a fixed prime. Have you checked this?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: It looks as though the question might be if there is partial progress in showing that any odd $n$ can be expressed as $p - a^2 - a$ for some $a$ and prime $p$.

Comment: @joro What do you mean? The polynomial clearly satisfies that.

Comment: I rewrote the first sentence in your post so that it can be interpreted as an actual question.

Comment: In 2008 I conjectured that any odd integer $n>3$ can be written as $p+a(a+1)$, where $p$ is a prime and $a$ is a positive integer. See my paper http://arxiv.org/abs/0803.3737.

Answer (score 4):

This problem is similar in flavor to the conjecture of Hardy and Littlewood that every large integer that is not a square, is the sum of a prime and a square. Miech (1968) proved that almost all integers have indeed this property, while Mikawa (1993) proved a short-interval refinement of this result. The proofs are based on the Hardy-Littlewood circle method, and I am sure much the same results can be derived for the problem of representing odd numbers in the form $p-a^2-a$ (with an updated singular series, of course).